# Why does no command advise the user to consult a man page on incorrect usage?

Tags: command-line, man

I recently gave a workshop on Linux tools and have been telling students to consult the man pages of commands should they run into errors.

However, I noticed that the command itself never returns a message to see the man page with the `man` command.

Most commands advise to use the `--help` option, use the `info` page, a blurb on the usage or just print the error message.

I am wondering why does no command ask the user to consult the man page? Wouldn't that be the first place to go looking when it is being used incorrectly?

Comment: `--help` is a terse prompt for the command, to refresh your memory. `man` is the detailed documentation. If you need to be told to read the `man` page, your problems extend beyond forgetting what the various options for a command are...

Comment: @jasonwryan Right, but one would think the `--help` message would lead users to `man`. I looked up the `--help` messages of some commands but none lead to the `man` page. There is almost no way a novice user would even know of `man` unless someone explicitly tells them to do so.

Comment: @Ketan: But the user only needs to be told once, not by every single utility. (I'd get severely annoyed if my utilities contained some repeated red tape about reading the man or info pages.) I believe the user should be told about `man`, and `man -k`, even `man -k topic | less`, before letting them on the command line, actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There *is* an objective reason for this.**

`--help` is a flag built in to the utility itself—built into the binary executable, or if it's a script then built into the script.

Man pages are stored separately on the filesystem from the executable itself.

**Man pages can be missing and the executable itself still accessible.**

As a utility developer, pointing users to a documentation resource which *may or may not* be present on their system makes less sense than inlining the information in the code itself.

---

Not only that, but **the version of the executable and the version of the man page may or may not line up.**

I have encountered this, for instance, when a version of Postgres was shipped with a certain package, and a different version of Postgres was also installed on the system.  `man psql` would show information for *one* version, but it wasn't the version you actually got by running `psql`.  If there were no `--help` flag, I would have had a big mystery why certain options didn't work according to the man page.

Answer (score 0):

This is subject to opinion because there likely are no statistics on how advice in error messages is presented.

The predominant tie-in which I have seen is to print the usage message (which may be more than one line), perhaps because telling someone to read the manual page was unnecessary.  Telling someone to read the `--help` message is redundant, and only a small fraction advise reading the info page.

All of the programs which I have developed provide a usage message (usually multiple lines).